# eventClick in vue fullCalendar has undefined props

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I have a pretty simple vuejs FullCalendar:

```
<FullCalendar
                defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                :displayEventTime='false'
                :plugins="calendarPlugins"
                :events="[
                    { title: 'event 1', date: '2020-03-01' },
                    { title: 'event 2', date: '2020-03-02' },
                    { title: 'event 3', date: '2020-03-02' }
                  ]"
                :header="{
                  left: 'prev,next',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,listMonth'
                }"
                @eventClick="eventClick"
                locale='fr-FR'
              />
```

And the eventClick event is as follow:

```
eventClick(arg){
      let coco = ""
      for(let what in arg.event){
        coco += "\n"+what+" => "+arg[what]
      }
      alert("eventMouseEnter: "+coco)
    }
```

I imported:

```
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'
```

In the alert all the referenced arg[what] are undefined.

For example:

> start => undefined
>
> end => undefined
>
> id => undefined
>
> groupId => undefined
>
> allDay => undefined
>
> title => undefined

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `arg.event[what]`, because you are iterating through the `arg.event` object?

Comment: Indeed, that is so silly. Thank you !